# mysql_real_escape_string not working on windows

Tags: php, windows-7

I am using PHP 5.2.17 on windows 7 and it is telling me that mysql_real_escape_string() is an undefined function. I was under the impression that it was built-in, so I have no idea why it would be undefined. Can anyone explain this and how to fix it?

Comment: It's not built in - it belongs to the "mysql' db extension. Is mysql_connect defined? If you only have PDO installed then you should use [PDO::quote](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.quote.php).

Answer (score 3):

That [`mysql_real_escape_string`<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) function is part of an extension, the [mysql extension](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysql.php). [Install it](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysql.installation.php) and you have the function.

Normally PHP on windows already ships with it and you only need to activate it in your php.ini file. See the link above about installing it, it has a section for the windows operating system.

Comment: Ah, I thought it was builtin. Thanks!

Comment: @Peter: Since some PHP versions it's no longer enabled by default. That was in the past, the installation page has the info in detail. Have fun!

Answer (score 1):

you need the mysql package for php5 also to use this function.